# Is 可能 a productive suffix?

Tags: grammar, suffixes

I learnt the phrase 再生可能なエネルギー today. The meaning of 再生可能 is clear, but it doesn't appear in any dictionaries I've looked at. In this case 可能 is like adding the suffix '-able' in English.

I wonder if this could be applied more generally. Can I freely add 可能 onto a word to get the 'word-able' version? If so, what would the grammar construction be to add it to the different parts of speech? Could you give some more examples please?

Comment: Hmm, I think it's case by case. Biodegradable plastic is called [生分解性プラスチック](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%94%9F%E5%88%86%E8%A7%A3%E6%80%A7%E3%83%97%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B9%E3%83%81%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF). In [SDGs](https://www.mofa.go.jp/mofaj/gaiko/oda/sdgs/about/index.html), sustainable is translated as 持続可能. But sustainable is often translated as サステナブル in a [chemical company](https://www.suntory.co.jp/company/csr/) in my opinion. I need to look it up more though, I think it depends on industries.

Comment: I believe in this case 再生可能 is a brand new word only spread after 2011 or so, which is why you don't find it. The online 大辞泉 lists the whole 再生可能エネルギー as a headword: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%86%8D%E7%94%9F%E5%8F%AF%E8%83%BD%E3%82%A8%E3%83%8D%E3%83%AB%E3%82%AE%E3%83%BC/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can attach 可能 to all suru-verbs (i.e., kango/gairaigo) as long as doing so makes sense.

- 施錠可能(な) lockable
- 検索可能(な) searchable
- 死亡可能(な) die-able(?)
  <sub>(e.g., 死亡可能回数 in life-based games such as *Super Mario*)</sub>
- 失敗可能イニシャライザ [failable initializer](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17)
- ペイント可能(な) paintable
- リサイクル可能(な) recyclable

But note that できる should be the initial choice in many cases. 可能 is used mainly in technical contexts. It's especially common when naming some concept (失敗できるイニシャライザ sounds too prose-like as a translation for *failable initializer*).

Related: [What's the difference between 不可能 and 不能?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/83102/5010)

Comment: I'm sure you're already aware but 'dieable' isn't a real word, so I guess I would never have even tried to construct that one. Interesting. 'Mortal' is probably the nearest equivalent.

Comment: @user3856370 Actually I was about to write 死亡可能 and 失敗可能 are impossible because they are nonsense, but then I googled and realized even these make sense in certain contexts. (And yes, I'm aware that my Chrome is showing me red wavy lines under "diable" and "failable".)

Comment: Not sure about "failable". It sounds right to me. Maybe because of my technical background.  It's interesting that adding 可能 is mainly used in technical contexts and yet you can use it to create a nonsense word used by gamers. Life is never consistent.

Comment: @user3856370 死ねる回数 ("the number of times you can die") should be much more common, but 死亡可能回数 also makes perfect sense and it sounds more or less more technical. So do you say "dieable" is wrong in English no matter what?

Comment: Yes, I have never heard the word 'dieable' before in my life.  When I read it above, I initially couldn't understand what it could possibly mean. Then I read your explanation about games and it became clear. Perhaps it is used amongst English speaking gamers but I don't know; that's not really my scene. I think 'mortal' is a much safer substitute and will definitely be understood by everyone.